# how to share on facebook within OSX app, without facebook Kit?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, swift, macos

I'm looking for way to use Accounts information if they configured in OS X, to post to Facebook, without using facebook kit.

I found Social framework but all examples are related to iOS, my App instead should post message from OS X.

Answer (score 0):

Using accounts is a good way to go, here's what I did:

```
    import Accounts

    static func post(text:String,completion:(Bool->Void)) {

        let accountStore = ACAccountStore()
        let accountType = accountStore.accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier(ACAccountTypeIdentifierFacebook)

        let options : [String:AnyObject] = [
            "ACFacebookAppIdKey": "your app key here, from Facebook apps",
            "ACFacebookPermissionsKey": ["publish_actions", "manage_pages", "publish_pages"],
            "ACFacebookAudienceKey": "ACFacebookAudienceEveryone"
        ]
        accountStore.requestAccessToAccountsWithType(accountType, options: options) {
            granted, error in

            if granted {
                let fbAccounts = accountStore.accountsWithAccountType(accountType)

                if fbAccounts != nil {
                    completion(true)
                } else {
                    print("no accounts")
                    completion(false)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Gabriel, thank you for your answer, looks like exactly that I searched. Only one thing I have doubts about - you mentioned "app key, from Facebook app", what if I have no any? I thought that if user granted access for his OS to communicate with facebook, I can post just after ask him about it, am I wrong?

Comment: @S.ork You need to register for a Facebook developer account and then get your app key from their website. That's the only hard bit of this whole process. An App key is necessary to do this.

Comment: Gabriel, thanks one more time, I registered, but found another question, probably it's obvious but I didn't understand where is your completion function, I mean where are you use text parametr???

Comment: @S.ork Sorry, didn't mean to include that. I was working on a `post` function that posted to Facebook, that `text` was the content to post, but I never finished that bit. I'm sure you can figure out how to use the credentials from the accounts. To get the first account do this: `fbAccounts[0]` and to get it's properties do this: `fbAccounts[0].valueForKey("properties")`